# boost::asio - initiating strand as a class member fails

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My code crashed when trying to initiate the strand member with adding another io_context

I had a class with io_context and a strand. The existing io_context is a reference, it is received in the constructor. I tried to create a new strand with a new io_context:

Class members:

```
boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
boost::asio::io_context io_context_2;
boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_2;
```

Constructor:

```
Server(
    boost::asio::io_context& ioc,
    : io_context_(ioc),
      io_context_2(),
      strand_(io_context_.get_executor()),
      strand_2(io_context_2.get_executor()),
       {
       }
```

I wanted to have both strands with different io_context, but because of the crash I was trying to test, and this also doesn't work:

```
Server(
    boost::asio::io_context& ioc,
    : io_context_(ioc),
      io_context_2(),
      strand_(io_context_.get_executor()),
      strand_2(io_context_.get_executor()),
       {
       }
```

But it does:

```
Server(
    boost::asio::io_context& ioc,
    : io_context_(ioc),
      //io_context_2(),
      strand_(io_context_.get_executor()),
      strand_2(io_context_.get_executor()),
       {
       }
```

The crash is in the line of initiating strand_2, it seems like io_context_2 fails to initiate when looking at the crash dump
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC8BD7FAAD (ntdll.dll) in server.exe.9124.dmp: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

in win_mutex.hpp - win_mutex::lock

Comment: I was able to guess your issue, and am 99.9% sure it's exactly that. There was no reason for you to not make the sample self-contained and actually *valid* reproducer of your problem. Please provide actual working (failing, in this case) code next time.

Comment: I knew the sample would work, I wondered if someone had the same issue, I assumes the solution wouldn't be naive. Anyways it was exactly me issue thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. And: always wear seatbelts (use warnings and sanitizers!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as described is fine:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56f4e68e224290bb)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

struct Server {
    using executor = asio::io_context::executor_type;
    asio::io_context&      io_context_;
    asio::io_context       io_context_2;
    asio::strand<executor> strand_;
    asio::strand<executor> strand_2;

    Server(asio::io_context& ioc)
        : io_context_(ioc)
        , io_context_2()
        , strand_(io_context_.get_executor())
        , strand_2(io_context_2.get_executor()) {}
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    Server s(ioc);

    ioc.run();
}
```

***Note how it runs cleanly with ASan and UBsan.***

### Guessing The Problem

Because the code is broken up in fragments, with many syntax errors and also probable typos (the first constructor initializer list should probably say `strand_2(io_context_2.get_executor())`), I'm pretty confident in saying that your real code looks different.

And from that I can basically **guess** what the problem is:

[image]

You can also see this **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/184f81b70a3d3afa)**

In case the problem is subtle to spot, you will see that the compiler actually tells you immediately if you enable minimal warnings:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -fsanitize=address,undefined && ./a.out
main.cpp: In constructor 'Server::Server(boost::asio::io_context&)':
main.cpp:10:28: warning: 'Server::strand_' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
   10 |     asio::strand<executor> strand_;
      |                            ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:8:28: warning:   'boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0> > Server::strand_2' [-Wreorder]
    8 |     asio::strand<executor> strand_2;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:5: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
   12 |     Server(asio::io_context& ioc)
```

The key thing to understand is that fields are initialized in the order in which they are **declared**. This is especially sensible with default member initializers: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order

So, enable warnings, and read them!